# Why The Value of HREF Attribute Adds Up With The Previous One

Tags: javascript, dom

I am creating a code which will automatically set the share button links in every HTML page.

Here is the piece of code.

```js
<script>

 x = window.location.href;
 var fbl = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=";
 var twitterl = "Hi%20!!!%20Check%20Out%20This%20Awesome%20Trick%20Now%20...%20:)%20Dont Miss It.%20";
 var gplusl = "http://plus.google.com/share?url=";
 var pinterestl = "http://pinterest.com/pinthis?url=";

 var fblink = document.getElementById("fb");
 var fbHref = fblink.getAttribute('href');
 fblink.setAttribute('href', fbHref + fbl + x);

 var twitterlink = document.getElementById("fb");
 var twitterHref = twitterlink.getAttribute('href');
 twitterlink.setAttribute('href', twitterHref + twitterl + x);

 var gpluslink = document.getElementById("fb");
 var gplusHref = twitterlink.getAttribute('href');
 gpluslink.setAttribute('href', gplusHref + gplusl + x);

 var pinterestlink = document.getElementById("fb");
 var pinterestHref = twitterlink.getAttribute('href');
 pinterestlink.setAttribute('href', pinterestHref + pinterestl + x);

</script>
```

```html
<div>
 <h4>Share This Page</h4>
  <a id="fb" href="" title="Share in Facebook" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="image/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" title="Facebook"></img></a>
  <a id="twitter" href="" title="Share in Twitter" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="image/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" title="Twitter"></img></a>
  <a id="gplus" href="" title="Share in Google Plus" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="image/gplus.png" alt="Google Plus" title="Google Plus"></img></a>
  <a id="pinterest" href="" title="Share in Pinterest" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="image/pinterest.png" alt="Pinterest" title="Pinterest"></img></a>
  </br></br>
</div>
```

The problem with this code is, the `href` attribute is adding up all together gradually.

I want the Facebook link to be `http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=currentpagelink`.

Answer (score 0):

You are always using the same ID (`fb`) instead of using the IDs of the links you want to change:

```
var fblink = document.getElementById("fb");
//                                   ^^^^
var twitterlink = document.getElementById("fb"); // should be "twitter"
//                                        ^^^^
// etc
```

Use the correct IDs and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

See if you need this: `Use proper Id's for related a tags` and you can directly use `document.getElementById("fb").href` to get the `href`.

```html
<div>
 <h4>Share This Page</h4>
  <a id="fb" href="" title="Share in Facebook" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="image/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" title="Facebook"></img></a>
  <a id="twitter" href="" title="Share in Twitter" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="image/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" title="Twitter"></img></a>
  <a id="gplus" href="" title="Share in Google Plus" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="image/gplus.png" alt="Google Plus" title="Google Plus"></img></a>
  <a id="pinterest" href="" title="Share in Pinterest" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="image/pinterest.png" alt="Pinterest" title="Pinterest"></img></a>
  </br></br>
</div>

<script>

 x = window.location.href;
 var fbl = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=";
 var twitterl = "Hi%20!!!%20Check%20Out%20This%20Awesome%20Trick%20Now%20...%20:)%20Dont Miss It.%20";
 var gplusl = "http://plus.google.com/share?url=";
 var pinterestl = "http://pinterest.com/pinthis?url=";

 var fblink = document.getElementById("fb");
 fblink.href=fbl + x;

 var twitterlink = document.getElementById("twitter");
 
 twitterlink.href=twitterl + x;

 var gpluslink = document.getElementById("gplus");
 gpluslink.href=gplusl + x;

 var pinterestlink = document.getElementById("pinterest");
 pinterestlink.href=pinterestl + x;

</script>
```

Comment: You might want to explain what you changed and why, instead of just posting some code with a meaningless description.

Comment: Oh Sorry Bro .. :( And Thank You Very Much For Helping. :)